# Iterate through multiple array lists with same index

Tags: java

Im a beginner in Java. I have 3 ArrayLists and all of the ArrayLists contain data pertaining to a specific subject and hence have the same length. I want to iterate through the array and perform some operations as illustrated below:

```
  public void example(){
  ArrayList<Long> ID = new ArrayList<Long>;
  ArrayList<Integer> AcNo = new ArrayList<Integer>;
  ArrayList<Integer> Vnum = new ArrayList<Integer>;

  //get ID and AcNo from user, compare it in the ArrayList, get the corresponding Vnum 
  // for the Vnum from previous step, compare it with the next Vnum and get corresponding ID and AcNo until some *condition* is satisfied.

  }
```

How do I do this in Java? I saw examples of Iterator, but Im not sure about the correct method to do this! Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If all three lists are of the same length, then iterate over them using **for loop** with indexes. Same indexes represents the same user in each of the three lists:

```
for (int i=0; i<ID.size(); i++) {
    Long userId= ID.get(i);
    Integer userAcNo= AcNo.get(i);
    Integer userVnum= Vnum.get(i);

    //if the next user exist, get the next user
    if (i + 1 < ID.size()) {
        Long nextUserId= ID.get(i+1);
        Integer nextUserAcNo= AcNo.get(i+1);
        Integer nextUserVnum= Vnum.get(i+1);

        //now compare userVariables and nextUser variables
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to have a single list of Subject objects or similar, so that each Subject contains all relevant data about itself.

```
class Subject {
    private final long id;
    private final int acNo;
    private final int vnum;

    /* Appropriate constructor and getters... */
}
```

You might also want to consider renaming the fields so that they are more descriptive.